# Restrict interface member access

Tags: c#

I have situation that my Orchestra class has given `IWatchService` parameter to consume either `FilesService` class or `DbService` class. All 3 members of `IWatchService` is used in `FilesService` and `DbService` class. In class Orchestra i want to have access to those methods besides method Watch() because method `Watch()` should be only used in either `DbService` or `FilesService` class but not in `Orchestra`. The problem is in `Orchestra` all three members will be visible to use. Is there any workaround to have `Watch()` not visible in `Orchestra`?

```
interface IWatchService
{
     void Watch();
     void MatchingFiles();
     void RemoteFiles();
}

interface IWatchServiceFiles : IWatchService { }

interface IWatchServiceDatabases : IWatchService { }

class FilesService : IWatchServiceFiles { }
class DbService : IWatchServiceDatabases { }

class Orchestra
{
    IWatchService WatchService
    public Orchestra(IWatchService watchService)
    {
        WatchService = watchService;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you lloking for explicit interface implementation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation

Comment: split your single interface into two (one with watch, the other with the other methods) and make Orchestra relate on the new one.

Comment: Why not separate `IWatchService` to two interfaces `IWatch` with `Watch` method and `IService` with the rest and then implement what you need where you need?

Comment: Is there *anything* besides the services themselves that need to access `Watch` via the interface? If not, why is it there *at all* if it's about how the services are *implemented*?

Comment: Why do you have both interface `IWatchServiceFiles` and `IWatchServiceDatabases`? Usually you handle difference within the concrete implementation...

Comment: @Johnny there is more than you see and it's more generic - i just simplified it to get the point. In real IWatchService contains shared staff and rest services interfaces  you mentioned are more complex and contains specific staff for specific classes.

Comment: @Jehof is it right to do such things? I mean if i want to use it somwhere else but not entire part you also extract new interface for such purpose?

Comment: @Henry look at interface aggregation principle

Comment: @DmitryBychenko i think your proposition will not work since in Orchestra's ctor param type is interface type means Watch will be still visible.

Comment: @Johnny you ment ISP to split interface into smaller parts like at following link? : https://code-maze.com/interface-segregation-principle/

Comment: @Henry yes, something like that